# Why can a reference declared with constexpr be bound to an Indeterminate value variable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
int aaa;
int& v = aaa;
int& rf = v;
constexpr int& crf = rf;
int main(){
}
```

I'm wondering why all compilers do agree on this example is well-formed? Isn't a constexpr variable should have a value that can be known during compiler time? Since the value of `aaa` has an Indeterminate value, why can this example be accepeted by compilers?

Comment: Global/static variables are zero-initialized by default. But it doesn't really matter here, because the reference only cares about the address being known at compile-time, not the value.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You're right, I forgot the value of `aaa` is zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this example, it appears to me it's equivalent to ask why the variable `rf` could be used in a constant expression. As per [dcl.constexpr#10], the full-expression of the initialization of `crf` should be a constant expression. According to [expr.const#11]

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with static storage duration that either is not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or if it is a non-immediate function.

In this case, since the reference binding should be bound to a glvalue, hence `rf` shall be a glvalue core constant expression; Since `rf` refers to the object `aaa` that has a static storage duration, hence we only should check whether `rf` is core constant expression, which is determined by [expr.const#5]. Since `rf` is an id-expression of reference type, hence it shall satisfy [expr.const#5.12]

> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
> > - it is usable in constant expressions or
> > - its lifetime began within the evaluation of E;

Here it must satisfy that it is usable in a constant expression, which is determined by [expr.const#4]

> A constant-initialized potentially-constant variable V is usable in constant expressions at a point P if V's initializing declaration D is reachable from P and
>
> > - V is constexpr,
> > - V is not initialized to a TU-local value, or
> > - P is in the same translation unit as D.
>
> An object or reference is usable in constant expressions if it is
>
> > - a variable that is usable in constant expressions, or

Since `rf` is a reference, hence it is potentially-constant due to [expr.const#3]

> A variable is potentially-constant if it is constexpr or it has **reference** or const-qualified integral or enumeration type.

Whether it is constant-initialized is determined by [expr.const#2]

> A variable or temporary object o is constant-initialized if
>
> > - [2.1] either it has an initializer or its default-initialization results in some initialization being performed, and
> > - [2.2] the full-expression of its initialization is a constant expression when interpreted as a constant-expression...

The declaration of `rf` has an initializer, bullet 2.1 is true, as far as now, whether `rf` is a constant expression has turned to examine whether its full-expression of the initialization is a constant expression. Again, `v` shall be a constant expression; to judge whether `v` is a constant expression is similar to the process of `rf` as given in above. Which in turn is to judge whether the initializer `aaa` is a constant expression, I say yes, since `aaa` is a static storage duration object and evaluating it will not violate any rule defined in [expr.const#5], hence it's a glvalue core constant expression. Hence, `v` is usable in constant expression, which means `rf` is also usable in a constant expression. In short, the full-expression of the initialization of `crf` is a constant expression.

In addition, regardless of `rf`, `v`, or `aaa`, they are all used as **glvalue core constant expression**, hence its value is not significant in this example.

Comment: Nice answer Jack, right down your alley with the many intricacies of reference initialization :)

Comment: @dfrib Hi, David. Long time no see. Welcome to you back!

Comment: Thanks! I think I've rekindled my language lawyer passion after a somewhat long hiatus :)

Comment: @dfrib Been a language lawyer will be being a language lawyer :)